# Generic that Extends a Generic, Passing Down Type

Tags: java

Forgive me if this question is a duplicate, I just have no idea how to phrase a Google search to come up with an answer.

First, I have an abstract class called `AsyncRoutine<Msg>`, it's generic, and specifies some sort of `Msg` type.

Next, I have an abstract `AsyncMessageProvider<T extends AsyncRoutine>`, designed to deliver a `Msg` to an `AsyncRoutine`.

Let's say I create a subclass `MyAsyncRoutine<Integer>` that extends `AsyncRoutine`. I'd like to make a `AsyncMessageProvider` that supports this class, so I'll subclass it, `MyAsyncMessageProvider<MyAsyncRoutine>` making `MyAsyncRoutine` its generic type.

Within `MyAsyncMessageProvider`, I have a method, `message(...)` that is called to pass a `Msg` along, in this case an `Integer`.

```java
public class MyAsyncMessageProvider extends AsyncMessageProvider<MyAsyncRoutine> {

    protected void message(Msg msg) { // compile error, doesn't know what 'Msg' is
    }

}
```

How can I access the generic type of `MyAsyncRoutine` (`Integer`) within `AsyncMessageProvider`? I basically want to make the `message(...)` function lock to whatever I specify in <> as I'm subclassing `AsyncMessageProvider`

Is it possible to do this without reflection? Or is there a better way to do this in general? I'd like to avoid using reflection if possible.

**Minimum Viable Example**

Abstract class definitions:

```java
public abstract class AsyncRoutine<Msg> {
 // Implementation not important
}
```

```java
public abstract class AsyncMessageProvider<Routine extends AsyncRoutine<Msg>> { // Compile error, cannot resolve Msg
    abstract void messageRoutine(Msg m); 
}
```

- How do I use `Msg` in `AsyncMessageProvider` so that it matches the generic `Msg` from "`AsyncRoutine<Msg>`" that I subclass `AsyncMessageProvider` with?

Comment: `public class MyAsyncMessageProvider<Msg> extends AsyncMessageProvider<MyAsyncRouting<Msg>>` solves it. Does it not?

Comment: @Gendarme beat me to it, but if that *doesn't* solve it, then you'd presumably just need to make sure your `message()` method took a parameter of type `T` rather than some other hardcoded type.

Comment: @MichaelBerry @Gendarme I need to access the generic type of `AsyncRoutine` within `AsyncMessageProvider`, so I can specify the template for message(), which when overriding in `MyAsyncMessageProvider` will default to whatever I extended. How do I define this in `AsyncMessageProvider`?

Comment: @wdavies973 Can you post a [mcve] so we can take a closer look? Perhaps it's just tiredness to blame on my end, but I'm not quite following at present.

Comment: @MichaelBerry I edited the question, does the addition make it clearer? I totally understand, this question is worded badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a type for it to your subclass:

```
public abstract class AsyncMessageProvider<Msg, Routine extends AsyncRoutine<Msg>> {
    abstract void messageRoutine(Msg m); 
}
```

——

Although this will compile, it’s the convention to use single letters for type names, ie:

```
public abstract class AsyncMessageProvider<T, Routine extends AsyncRoutine<T>> {
    abstract void messageRoutine(T t); 
}
```

Doing this makes it clear to readers what the type is, because they’re used to seeing single letter names. Someone reading this:

```
abstract void messageRoutine(Msg m);
```

would be excused if they thought the method was expecting an instance of a *class* named `Msg`.

The problem become worse when you actually have a class named `Msg` because the type of the same name shadows the corresponding class, which will make your coworkers sad.